# how to do this in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 public function in My Controller

```
 public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::personal()->get();
    return view('projects.index')->withProject($projects);
}
```

other one is

```
 public function show($id) {
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $tasks = $this->getTasks($id);
    $files = $this->getFiles($id);
    $comments = $this->getComments($id);
    $collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($id);
    return view('projects.show')->withProject($project)->withTasks($tasks)->withFiles($files)->withComments($comments)->withCollaborators($collaborators);}
```

I need get

```
$collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($id);
```

to My public function index() method to print collaborators in ('projects.index') view

how can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Update your index function with this code, haven't tested it

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::personal()->get();

    foreach($projects as $key => $project) {
        $find = Project::find($project->id);
        $tasks = $this->getTasks($project->id);
        $files = $this->getFiles($project->id);
        $comments = $this->getComments($project->id);
        $collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($project->id);   
        $projects[$key]['collaborators'] = $collaborators;
    }

    return view('projects.index')->withProject($projects);
}
```

In ('projects.index') you will have collaborators value for each database record

Comment: did it but occured following errors Undefined variable: collaborators (View: C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop\c\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)